# Batch file: start at high priority with cmd blocked

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

My goal: run a batch file in high priority without opening task manager.

The problem is at school `cmd.exe` is blocked (due to restrictions), but I can run batch files via Windows Explorer or using VBScript function `.Run` or `.ShellExecute`. It works when I use `.Run "G:\test.bat"` but not `.Run "cmd /c G:\test.bat"`. It doesn't work when I use the `start` function in a batch file to start another batch file. In this case I get an error similar to "This program is blocked by policy". I get that same error when I run `cmd.exe` from "Start > Run > cmd".

So somehow when I run a batch file from a VBScript, Windows doesn't detect it's using `cmd` which is blocked. I wonder if if there is a VBScript function that starts a program with high priority. Maybe it would be in another file extention and another language. Or if you have another idea post it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use WMI to accomplish this. You'll need to use the [`Win32_ProcessStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class in conjunction with [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to define the startup parameters and run your batch file. Use the `PriorityClass` property of the `Win32_ProcessStartup` class to specify a priority for your spawned process.

```
Const PRIORITY_CLASS_HIGH = 128

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
Set objStartup = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ProcessStartup")

Set objConfig = objStartup.SpawnInstance_
objConfig.PriorityClass = PRIORITY_CLASS_HIGH

Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
objProcess.Create "G:\test.bat", null, objConfig, intProcessID
```

Answer (score 0):

On 32 bit windows the command.com still runs if cmd is blocked. And you are lucky the admin didn't tick the check box disabling bat files in the dialog where you disable cmd.

command.com in WinNT passes all commands to cmd.exe for execution. Start command and type away.

Also nothing stops you using the command prompt, it just exits after each command. To do a dir

```
cmd /k dir
```

it will do a dir then exit.

so

```
cmd /k start /high notepad
```

This is the description of the policy with me bolding certain words.

Disable the command prompt 
User Configuration\Administrative Templates\System

Description
Prevents users from running the **interactive** command prompt, Cmd.exe. This policy also determines whether batch files (.cmd and .bat) can run on the computer.

If you enable this policy and the user tries to open a command window, the system displays a message explaining that a policy prevents the action.

Caution

Do not prevent the computer from running batch files if the computer uses logon, logoff, startup, or shutdown batch file scripts, or for users that use Terminal Services.

---